# spring security keycloak adapter

Tags: spring, spring-security, keycloak

I'm trying to use Keycloak with my spring boot application.

I want to restrict access to a particular URL based on the REST method and user's role.

In the example below, users with any of the roles `view-all` or `calendar` can perform a GET, while those with `manage-all` or `calendar_manage` can do a POST, PUT, or DELETE.

Unfortunately, this configuration is allowing any authenticated user access to the /api/calendar URL.  What am I doing wrong?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/calendar/*").hasAnyRole("view-all", "calendar")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/calendar/*").hasAnyRole("manage-all", "calendar_manage")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/calendar/*").hasAnyRole("manage-all", "calendar_manage")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/calendar/*").hasAnyRole("manage-all", "calendar_manage");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with **isAuthenticated** and **hasAnyAuthority** and permission to  ("/api/**")

```
       @Configuration
        @EnableWebSecurity
        class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        ...
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
            {
                super.configure(http);
                http    .authorizeRequests()
                        .csrf().disable()
                        .antMatcher("/api/**").permitAll()
                        .isAuthenticated()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/calendar/*").hasAnyAuthority("view-all", "calendar")
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/calendar/*").hasAnyAuthority("manage-all", "calendar_manage")
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/calendar/*").hasAnyAuthority("manage-all", "calendar_manage")
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/calendar/*").hasAnyAuthority("manage-all", "calendar_manage");
            }
        }
```

Comment: doesn't compile :-(

Answer (score 0):

the trick is - you need a `/**` at the end of the path in the ant matchers!

(I had to step thru the spring code to figure it out - see method `doMatch()` in Spring Core's `AntPathMatcher` class)

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/calendar/**")
    .hasAnyRole("view-all", "calendar", "calendar_manage")
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/calendar/**")
    .hasAnyRole("manage-all", "calendar_manage")
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/calendar/**")
     .hasAnyRole("manage-all", "calendar_manage")
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/calendar/**")
    .hasAnyRole("manage-all", "calendar_manage")
```